# Vuetify input autocomplete bug

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried to google it a couple of times but got no luck, basically, when the page loads since the password is on autosave the v-text-field doesn't understand it and renders the password content in front of the label, is there any workaround or fix for that?

Here is a ss:

[image]

The login component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-card class="elevation-12">
      <v-toolbar color="primary" dark flat>
        <v-toolbar-title>Login</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form>
          <v-text-field
            label="E-mail"
            name="email"
            type="text"
            :rules="emailRules"
            :autofocus="'autofocus'"
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            id="password"
            label="Senha"
            name="password"
            type="password"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="primary" block>Logar</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "LoginForm",
    data: () => ({
      valid: true,
      email: '',
      password:'',
      emailRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Digite um e-mail',
        v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'O e-mail precisa ser válido.',
      ]
    })
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "LoginForm.scss";
</style>
```

The place where I use the login component:

```
 <template>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid fill-height>
      <v-layout align-center justify-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
          <LoginForm></LoginForm>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</template>

<script>
import LoginForm from "../components/login/LoginForm";
import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'
import VuetifyLogo from '~/components/VuetifyLogo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {
    LoginForm,
    Logo,
    VuetifyLogo
  },
  data: () => ({
  }),
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code snippets, not just pictures.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Update June 4, 2021**. Tested on Vuetify 2.5.3 and Google Chrome 90:

You can still use **placeholder** prop with one space in combination with **persistent-placeholder** prop.

```
...
<v-text-field
  label="Login"
  v-model="loginItem.login"
  placeholder=" "
  persistent-placeholder
  :rules="rules.login"
/>
```

---

**Old answer.** This solution stopped working starting from vuetify 2.4.0 (thanks [@saike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330193) for the info):

As a simple workaround you could add **placeholder** prop with one space:

```
...
<v-text-field
  label="Login"
  v-model="loginItem.login"
  placeholder=" "
  :rules="rules.login"
></v-text-field>
...
<v-text-field
  label="Password"
  placeholder=" "
  v-model="loginItem.password"
  type="password"
  :rules="rules.password"
></v-text-field>
...
```

That's how it looks like when login/password was saved in your browser (in my case it's Google Chrome 80):

[image: Autosaved]

And with empty values:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely genius!

Comment: unfortunately not working in `"vuetify": "^2.4.0"`, i use `this.$refs.EmailField.focus()` in `mounted` hook

Comment: Thanks for the info, @saike. Unfortunately, on latest vuetify 2.5.3 calling **focus** method in `mounted` hook leads to a situation when only the field on which it was called is displayed correctly, while the other field remains overlapped. I have updated my answer with a more correct solution to the problem

Comment: nice, anyway to have the labels lowered on load if there is nothing in there?

Comment: @Zaffer, no, not yet :(

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is generating a random `name` attribute. With my solution I used `uuid` `v4` method. If you rely on name then obviously this might not work for you unless you keep a map of names -> v4 output.

```
import { v4 } from 'uuid'
```

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="card"
    class="card-input"
    outlined
    :name="v4()"
    label="Credit Card Number"
    :rules="creditCardNumberRules"
    v-mask="[' ####  ####  ####  ####', ' ####  ####  #####  ###']"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. A text field component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field :style="passwordStyle" type="text" v-model="inputValue" />

    <v-btn
      class="ma-2"
      color="primary"
      @click="showPassword = !showPassword"
      :disabled="!inputValue"
    >
      {{ showPassword ? "Hide" : "Show" }}
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      showPassword: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    passwordStyle() {
      return {
        "font-family": this.showPassword ? "helvetica" : "password",
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@font-face {
  font-family: "password";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an answer but I found a fix that doesn't require sacrificing Vuetify's placeholder labels. It's a bit of a hack based on this article:

https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/detecting-chrome-autofill-on-page-load-78ea178e4a68

Unfortunately, because Chrome doesn't fire any events when autocompleting a form, it relies on a setInterval, and it hard inserts classes onto Vuetify elements which may break in future versions, but it otherwise works like a charm.

Add the following to your component (or globally to your app if you like)

```
export const detectAutofill = (selector) => {

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const element = document.querySelector(selector);

        if (element) {
            const isAutofill = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue("appearance") === "menulist-button";

            if (isAutofill) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);

                const textParent = element.closest('.v-input');
                textParent.classList.add('v-input--is-dirty', 'v-input--is-label-active');
                const textLabel = textParent.querySelector('.v-label');
                if (textLabel) textLabel.classList.add('v-label--active');
            }
        }
    }, 50);

};
```

And then in your mounted method, invoke it with a selector. In my case, I am checking for username and password inputs like so:

```
detectAutofill("input[type=text]");
detectAutofill("input[type=password]");
```

It uses a mutation observer to wait for the element to appear (in case you are using v-if) and checks for autocomplete, then adds relevant classes to the corresponding markup.