# Vuetify v-text-field autocomplete displaying problem at login

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify `v-card-text` inputs for my login page and the autocomplete displays the value on top of the label, which creates this annoying glitch. When I click on the inputs the labels clear out.

How do I get rid of label if the autocomplete is on?

[image]

```
         <v-text-field
                                :rules="emailRules"
                                autocomplete
                                label="Email"
                                v-model="login.mail"
                        ></v-text-field>
                        <v-text-field
                                :rules="passwordRules"
                                autocomplete
                                label="Password"
                                type="password"
                                v-model="login.password"
                                v-on:keypress.enter="submit()"
                        ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Without one, there is no way of testing if a potential solution would work in your case.

Comment: @philx94 take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160260/vuetify-input-autocomplete-bug/). Possibly this is what you need.

Comment: perfect. This workaround works

Answer (score -1):

I don't think v-text-field has autocomplete props. [Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/)