# How to fix overlapping text by autocomplete (Vuetify)?

Tags: forms, vue.js, input, vuetify.js

I create Vue application with a login form.
In this form, after refreshing the page, the inputs are automatically completed ff they are remembered. But here is the problem because for example user password and the string input "Password" overlap and it looks bad:

[image]

After clicking on input it fixes itself:

[image]

Template:

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field
      type="password"
      v-model="form.password"
      label="Password"
      required
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      password: "",
    },
  }),
  computed: {
    userData() {
      return {
        password: this.form.password,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How to fix it?

Edit:
I tried all the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264017/how-fix-issue-with-chrome-auto-complete-overlap-with-labels-in-vuetify) but it doesn't work for me, there is still a problem.

Comment: This issue already got answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264017/how-fix-issue-with-chrome-auto-complete-overlap-with-labels-in-vuetify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How fix issue with chrome auto complete overlap with labels in vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264017/how-fix-issue-with-chrome-auto-complete-overlap-with-labels-in-vuetify)

Comment: I tried all the solutions from this question but it doesn't work for me, there is still the problem

Comment: Solutions from this question don't work because they are obsolete, the solution to my question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160260/vuetify-input-autocomplete-bug)